# Can you run tkinter on cs50 ide?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an assignment where I have to use Tkinter in a python program. After doing some research I found out that I should be able to use Tkinter to display a window. However, after setting up with these lines

```
something = tkinter.Tk()

something.title("My First Tkinter Window")

something.mainloop()

something.geometry("600x400")
```

I got the error

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

Now I'm wondering, can you even do this on cs50 ide, which I use for programming python? Or am I just doing something the wrong way?

Comment: I suppose ```something.geometry("600x400")``` should come before ```something.mainloop()```

Comment: It is an online IDE which may not have a graphical desktop environment that tkinter requires.

Comment: on what interface should I program that has a graphical desktop environment? I downloaded python 3.9 but I don't really understand how to use it lol. i'm rather new to this

Comment: If your platform is Windows or Mac, you already have the graphical desktop environment.  If your platform is Linux, you should have it except you use a server distribution which don't start/have the graphical desktop environment.  Just install Python and tkinter (which is not included in Python in some Linux distributions), then you can execute your Python script in a console/terminal.